# JAVA Thread как уничтожить

Tags: java, многопоточность

Не получается уничтожить Thread

```
void disable(){
    System.out.println("thread disable" + isActive);
    isActive=false;
}
  
void MyThread(){
   isActive = true;
}
  
public void run(){
      

    while(isActive){
        try {
            System.out.println("thread enable " + isActive);
            Thread.sleep(60000); // 1000 - 1 сек

            

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    
}
```

Запускаю вызовом метода MyThread и run
все окей, вызываю метод disable он выполняется, но тред остается активным, что не так делаю?

Comment: Где вы пытаетесь вызвать метод?

Comment: [Thread.interrupt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) прерывает работу немедленно если нить спит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Убедитесь, что isActive у вас volatile:

```
private volatile boolean isActive;
```

Без volatile изменения не будут видны в другом потоке потому цикл никогда не остановится.

И как правильно заметил [Stanislav Volodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/416121/stanislav-volodarskiy) пока поток спит в `Thread.sleep` изменения `isActive` никак на него не повлияют. Т.е. в вашем случае остановка может занять до 60 секунд, пока поток не проснется.

Правильный способ остановить будет послать interrupt. Итого рабочий пример:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
  private volatile boolean isActive = true;

  void disable() {
    System.out.println("thread disable" + isActive);
    isActive = false;
    this.interrupt();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (isActive) {
      try {
        System.out.println("thread enable " + isActive);
        Thread.sleep(60000); // 1000 - 1 сек
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String argv[]) throws InterruptedException {
    MyThread thread = new MyThread();
    thread.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000); // даем время потоку запуститься и заснуть
    thread.disable();   // останавливаем
    thread.join();      // ждем завершения потока
  }
}
```

Раз уж в комментарии появились возражения, то еще дополню касательно необходимости использовать `volatile` для переменной используемой в качестве флага для остановки одного потока из другого. Вот пример из [спецификации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) языка с моим переводом:

> Например, в следующем (сломаном) фрагменте кода, предполагаем, что this.done это не-volatile поле типа boolean

```
while (!this.done)
    Thread.sleep(1000);
```

> Компилятор может прочитать поле this.done один раз, и испльзовать кешированное значение при каждом выполении цикла. Это означает, что цикл никогда не закончится, даже если другой поток изменит значение this.done.

Comment: Я никогда не ставил volatile на переменную потока, и тем не менее поток останавливался, когда значение переменной менялось.

Comment: @RomanC volatile не единственный способ синхронизации, скорее всего, у вас была синхронизация и без volatile.  Чтоб говорить по существу нужно рассматривать конкретный код.

Comment: Во первых, volatile ничего не синхронизует, во вторых из кода вообще ничего не понятно что там вообще надо синхронизировать.

Comment: `volatile` безопасно публикует изменения сделанные в одном потоке. Когда я писал "синхронизирует" это я упростил немного, "синхронизирует" в том смысле, что синхронизирует то, как два потока видят значение переменной. Без правильной публикации изменений (а volatile это один из способов это сделать) у каждого может быть своя копия переменной и поток ее именно что не синхронизирует с другими.

Comment: Я мог бы продолжить дискуссию по поводу volatile, что это *необходимо*, в случае, если вы уберёт его, и ваш код перестанет работать.

Comment: Этот код работает без volatile, но только по той причине, что в цикле есть вызов `System.out.println`, который внутри себя делает какие-то операции, которые синхронизируют память (т.е. читает что-то из volatile переменной или имеет synchronized блок). Если убрать `System.out.println` - то без volatile не работает.

Comment: `System.out.println` тут не причем, и `volatile` в вашем примере абсолютно не нужен, так как код работает без него. См. [пример](https://ideone.com/1LpNFy)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124802/discussion-between-roman-konoval-and-roman-c).

Comment: У меня сработало, спасибо большое